# Android LinearLayout is adding extra space at bottom

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-linearlayout

When I go to put elements in my LinearLayout and format them to fill up the size of the layout, I get this blank or white space at the bottom of the layout. It would appear that there is something going on with the margins but I can't seem to figure it out.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/botHand3"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/botTile3_0"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="-3dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/botTile3_1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="-3dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="-3dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/botTile3_2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="-3dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="-3dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/botTile3_3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="-3dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="-3dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/botTile3_4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="-3dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="-3dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/botTile3_5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="-3dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="-3dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/botTile3_6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="-3dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="-3dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/botTile3_7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="-3dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="-3dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/botTile3_8"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="-3dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="-3dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/botTile3_9"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="-3dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I don't ever get the error when the LinearLayout is horizontal. Also, when I set the gravity to center, the whitespace is divided between the top and bottom of the layout.

Comment: Why do you use `alignParentBottom|Left|Top` if your height is `fill_parent`?

Comment: That still didn't fix anything or even change it

Comment: Also another curious question, why using `Relative+LinearLayout` whereas you could have only one `LinearLayout` as a parent view.. no? And try to set `android:weightSum="10"` to your linearlayout.

Comment: It's part of a larger application with the need for multiple `LinearLayout`s. This is just one particular piece of it and bringing it into its own layout, it was giving me the same problems. The weightSum didn't do anything either =/

Comment: @NareshR Yes, when I took out the negative values for the margin is corrected itself

Answer (score 0):

That's probably happening because your last button is bigger than the space left in the activity view, so it can't render properly if you do not set your view as ScrollView.

So, in this case you should define a ScrollView type to your view OR reduce your button heights to correctly fill your view actual height.

However, if you just want to add the ScrollView, try the following as example:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/botHand3"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/botTile3_0"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="-3dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/botTile3_1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="-3dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="-3dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/botTile3_2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="-3dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="-3dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/botTile3_3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="-3dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="-3dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/botTile3_4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="-3dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="-3dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/botTile3_5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="-3dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="-3dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/botTile3_6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="-3dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="-3dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/botTile3_7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="-3dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="-3dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/botTile3_8"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="-3dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="-3dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/botTile3_9"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="-3dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Good luck!

Comment: It worked (kinda) for having 10 buttons in the layout but I'm wanting 13 total and after that, they're spilling off. I think 10 happened to be a nice number for this specific screen height

Comment: They are splitting, but addin the ScrollView tag you should be able to scroll down your view and see the splitted buttons, different than before, when they just do not show at the view at all.

Comment: But with this, I don't want them to scroll, I want the heights to be even amongst the buttons and to fill the entire layout. Ultimately, the way I have it in my question, all the buttons show, it's just there's this whitespace that's present at the bottom of the `LinearLayout`. Doing this horizontally has given me no issues.